# Flutter Firebase update value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching data from my collection on firebase inside listview :

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db.collection('encheres').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map<Widget>(
                      (doc) {
                        return Card(
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       );
```

I wanna update value of certain attribute on onPressed, any ideas how to achieve that ?

And thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `onPressed` handler you can update the document with

```
doc.reference.update({'field': 'new value'})
```

Also see the FlutterFire document on [updating documentds](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#updating-documents).